# can't call jquery custom function in separate js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, file

I'm trying to move my slideshow function `runShow()` into a seperate **.js** file named **panzoomslideshow.js**
This is simply to separate my script into another file that is then used by all my pages.
I can get the *resize trigger* to fire an alert, but it won't call the `runShow ()` function - what am I doing wrong?  I got it to run before, but now I can't!

The script to call **panzoomslideshow.js** in the head of my web page and this is where on each resize, the `runShow()` function in the **panzoomslideshow.js** file function is called:

```
<script type="text/javascript">         //*** This will reload the player upon resizing! ***\\
var resizeTimer;
$(window).resize(function() {
    clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(runShow(), 100);
});
</script>
```

I should note I also tried putting the $(function(){ }) around it, but then all the variables can't be accessed from the runShow() function which won't run...

panzoomslideshow.js ->

```
    var dur = 2000;
    var pDur = 4500;    
    var vp_width = window.innerWidth;
    var vp_height = window.innerHeight;
    var width_large = 880; 
    var height_large = 495; 
    var width_medium = 720; 
    var height_medium = 405;    
    var width_small = 480;  
    var height_small = 270; 
    var width_micro = 320;  
    var height_micro = 180;     

    var slide_width;
    var slide_height;
    var anim_width;
    var anim_height;    
    var margin_top;
    var margin_left;    
    alert("The Global variables are set, like vp_width and vp_height are "+vp_width+" and "+vp_height);

    runShow();  

function runShow() {

    if(vp_width <= 320){                        //SET Micro size
        slide_width = width_micro;
        slide_height = height_micro;
        anim_width = (width_micro * 1.2);
        anim_height = (height_micro * 1.2); 
        margin_top = -30;
        margin_left = -60;      
    } else if(vp_width <= 480){                 //SET small size
        slide_width = width_small;
        slide_height = height_small;
        anim_width = (width_small * 1.2);
        anim_height = (height_small * 1.2); 
        margin_top = -70;
        margin_left = -150;         
    } else if(vp_width <= 1140){                //SET Medium size
        slide_width = width_medium;
        slide_height = height_medium;
        anim_width = (width_medium * 1.2);
        anim_height = (height_medium * 1.2);    
        margin_top = -80;
        margin_left = -180;             
    } else if(vp_width <= 1400){                //SET Large size
        slide_width = width_large;
        slide_height = height_large;
        anim_width = (width_large * 1.2);
        anim_height = (height_large * 1.2);             
        margin_top = -100;
        margin_left = -200;
    } else {
        //do nothing since the screen size is too small???
    }       

    alert("runShow() is invoked! Slideshow Width and Height will be "+slide_width+" and "+slide_height+" The Global variables are set, like vp_width and vp_height are "+vp_width+" and "+vp_height);

    $(".carousel").carouFredSel({
        items: {
            visible: 1,
            width: slide_width,
            height: slide_height
        },
        scroll: {
            fx: "fade",
            easing: "linear",
            duration: dur,
            timeoutDuration: pDur,
            onBefore: function( data ) {
                animate( data.items.visible, pDur + ( dur * 3 ) );
            },
            onAfter: function( data ) {
                data.items.old.find( "img" ).stop().css({
                    width: slide_width,
                    height: slide_height,
                    marginTop: 0,
                    marginLeft: 0
                });
            }
        },
        onCreate: function( data ) {
            animate( data.items, pDur + ( dur *2 ) );
        }
    });

    function animate( item, dur ) {
        var obj = {
            width: anim_width,
            height: anim_height
        };
        switch( Math.ceil( Math.random() * 2 ) ) {
            case 1:
                obj.marginTop = 0;
                break;
            case 2:
                obj.marginTop = -80
                break;
        }
        switch( Math.ceil( Math.random() * 2 ) ) {
            case 1:
                obj.marginLeft = 0;
                break;
            case 2:
                obj.marginLeft = -170
                break;
        }
        item.find( "img" ).animate(obj, dur, "linear" );
    }

};
```

Comment: Where is the inline script placed? in body or head section?

Comment: It may be preferable to create a globle object (namespace) to place your top-level functions to avoid cluttering the global namespace. For example, at the top of your code, something like var myApp = {}, and then myApp.runShow = function() {};

Comment: try passing a function reference instead `setTimeout(runShow, 100);`

Answer (score 2):

:)
Did you try this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //your javascript code
});
```

Comment: Aaah of course - the function hadn't been loaded yet...

Thanks mate :D

Comment: but using document.ready doesn't really have anything to do with the file loading...that's for the DOM to be loaded.

Most likely, your function was declared _after_ it was used and the document.ready provided the necessary delay so your function was then declared _before_ it was invoked.

Comment: But, using document.ready is still good advice for when you need to do dom manipulation to make sure the DOM has loaded :)

Comment: Aah right, well it worked :)
I added the .js file first, so in my mind it should be ready by the time I get to the resize trigger, but for some reason wasn't - `$(document).ready(function ()` at least fixes that.

@Dhanasekar S M 
The script part was in the header of my document.

I now put runShow() inside a `$(document).ready(function ()` before I do the re-size trigger, to get the slideshow to run on page load, then reload after each re-sizing . . .